# TestNG: initialise data provider once for all methods

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Currently I have a test class which has multiple methods all using the same data provider. Each time testng loops through the different methods, it recomputes the data provider method. Is there any way I can make the data provider run once?

Thanks!

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Factories](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) are exactly what you are looking for.